# Speeding up Microsoft's Unity Container (dependency injection)

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

We are using Microsoft Unity in an ASP.NET application.  Profiling my application (with Jetbrains) on my local box, I don't see any unity issues.  However, on our staging server, a powerful box with 12GB of memory, I sometimes see an unusual amount of time spent loading unity configurations. (Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.ConfigureContainer())

[image]

Here's an example where 480ms are spent loading a single unity configuration.  Half a second here, half a second there, it can add up.  We are configuring unity via XML (changing this is not an option).  Anyone seen this and/or have thoughts on how to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't seeing any CPU spikes during my testing, but once I made an unrelated performance improvement which made my site dramatically faster, the time spent on Unity dropped too low to be measured.  So I guess it was my other performance issue was negatively affecting Unity, and the performance of Unity itself is fine.